# Connection Error with MySQL connector in SSIS

Tags: mysql

I have used MySql connector 6.6.5. Connection to the local database works, but to connect to the database on the hosting does not work. Create a connection, enter - server name, user name, password . I open the combo box `Database name` - show error `unable to retrieve the list of database`.

OS - Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
Sql Server version 2008

Comment: Does the hosting has the user you are try to connect? Also, does the host has the permission to access it from external location for that user?

Comment: Yes. hosting has user which I used for connection and access permission is provided to that user in the external location.

Comment: Can you show the results of the `select host, user from users;` of the mysql database ?